# Call to a member function paginate() on array when use in variable

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-livewire

I get information from the web service but this error is given when I try to do the pagination
I saw other questions but they all took information from the database and did not help my problem.

```
Call to a member function paginate() on array (View: /media/mojtaba/Work/Project/bit/resources/views/backend/crypto/cryptolist.blade.php)
```

and my code:

```
    public function render()
    {
        try {
                $api = new \Binance\API('api','secret');
                $prices = $api->coins();
                $one = json_encode($prices, true);

                $coins = json_decode($one , true);
            return view('livewire.backend.crypto.cryptolist')->with('coins' , $coins->paginate(10));
        }catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            return view('wrong')->with('e' , $e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your passing paginate(), in json_decode which is not meant, it will return an array, paginate() is for QueryBuilder and eloquent only and in collection or something

Comment: Is there no way to paginate this?@Jerson

Comment: you can make it

Comment: I don't know why people do just not read the errors. call to a member function paginate on array... So your variable where you call ->paginate() is an array.

Comment: @Jerson Can you help more or give a link to create a pagination

Comment: I know the problem is here, I do not know how to solve this problem because I get the information from the api @GertB.

Comment: @MojtabaDelshad doesn't the API provide pagination? If i google it, it does.

Comment: @MojtabaDelshad try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Collection` for this, but collection has no `paginate` method but we can use `macros` to `extend` it

Open `AppServiceProvider.php` and paste this on `boot` method

```
Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
    $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

    return new LengthAwarePaginator(
        $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
        $total ?: $this->count(),
        $perPage,
        $page,
        [
            'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
            'pageName' => $pageName,
        ]
    );
});
```

also `import` this incase

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
```

then in your `render` method you can, use `collect([...])->paginate(10)` just like below

```
public function render() {
    try {
        $api = new \Binance\API('api','secret');
        $coins = $api->coins();

        return view('livewire.backend.crypto.cryptolist')->with('coins',collect($coins)->paginate(10));
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return view('wrong')->with('e' , $e);
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/iamsajidjaved/4bd59517e4364ecec98436debdc51ecc) for extending `paginate` method with `Collection` using `macros`.